# Copy time-machine backup to Linux?

Tags: linux, centos, time-machine, hfs+, netatalk

I am trying to copy my time-machine backup from an external USB drive to a linux powered netatalk server. For this, I removed the SATA hard drive from its enclosure and connected it directly to the PC. I was able to mount the drive using [hfsplus fuse driver](http://www.spidersoft.com.au/2011/centos-6-and-mac-os-extended-hfs-plus-support/) and rsync the entire mount point to the larger disk in the PC. But, somewhere amist the transfer, kernel panics and everything freezes. From what is displayed on screen, it is clear that the hfsplus driver is causing it.

Are there any other ways of copying this data? Preferably without my macbook being involved.

Answer (score 4):

When I wanted to do the same thing, I just automounted it with the standard HFS drivers (Ubuntu 12.10) and used [tmfs](https://github.com/abique/tmfs) to get directory hard links working. For me this worked out fine, here's a small [writeup](http://boundaryfunctions.wordpress.com/2013/01/23/breaking-the-apple-lock-in-time-machine/) of what I did. This should pretty much work the same with CentOS.